# Product of Elements in a Finite Cyclic Group with Odd or Even Order

Tags: cyclic-groups

**Assuming that G is a finite cyclic group, let "a" be the product of all the elements in the group.**

i.  **If G has odd order, then a=e.** Is this because there are an even number of non-trivial elements must have their inverses within the non-trivial factors within the product?

ii.  **If G has even order then a is not equal to e.**  Here there an odd number of non-trivial elements. There must also be an odd number of elements who are their own inverses, and therefore a cannot equal e?

Thanks for any help! I'm just reading a textbook and trying practice problems!

Comment: Your statements are true. Try to improve the writing.

Comment: This is essentially Wilson's theorem for finite abelian groups: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson's_theorem#Gauss.27s_generalization.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Makes complete sense now. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Since we know it is a finite cyclic group,

**Hint:** $ 1 + 2 + \ldots + n = \frac {n (n+1)}{2}$

This is a multiple of $n$ if $n$ is odd, and not a multiple of $n$ if $n$ is even.

---

Your statements are true, and don't just apply to a finite cyclic group. I would prefer your solution over mine, but I think the above is what the textbook had in mind.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\,G=\langle x\rangle =\{1\,,\,x\,,\,x^2\,,\,\ldots\,,\,x^{n-1}\}\,$:

$$x\cdot x^2\cdot\ldots\cdot x^{n-1}=x^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}=\begin{cases}x^{(n-1)k}\neq 1&\,,\,\,\text{ if}\,\;\;\;n=2k\,\,\,\text{ is even}\\{}\\x^{kn}=1&\,,\,\text{ if}\,\;\;n-1=2k\,\,\,\text{is even}\end{cases}$$